# What is a Python buffer object pointing to the start of the array’s data?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
A = np.arange(12)
B = A.reshape(3, 4)
A[0] = 42
print(B)
print(A)
print(np.may_share_memory(A, B))
print(A.data == B.data)
```

Running above code, I am surprised that `print(A.data == B.data)` returns `False`. It seems A and B are sharing some memory, and their first element should be shared. Then if `numpy.ndarray.data` is an object pointing to the start of the array’s data (as the document said), it is expected to produce the same result on `A` and `B`.

Comment: `A.data == B.data` compares two Python memoryview objects (not the memory address of the buffer) which are unequal because shape/stride information differs.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `__array_interface__` as a way of looking at the attributes, including data buffer address:

```
In [766]: A = np.arange(12)
In [767]: B = A.reshape(3,4)
In [768]: A[0] = 42
In [769]: A
Out[769]: array([42,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
In [770]: B
Out[770]: 
array([[42,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [771]: A.data
Out[771]: <memory at 0xb16ef5dc>
In [772]: B.data
Out[772]: <memory at 0xb1719cdc>
In [773]: A.__array_interface__
Out[773]: 
{'data': (156295616, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (12,),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
In [774]: B.__array_interface__
Out[774]: 
{'data': (156295616, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (3, 4),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
```

`A.__array_interface__['data'][0]` values do match

The documentation for `A.data` is:

> Python buffer object pointing to the start of the array’s data

but to ordinary Python programmers that can be misleading.  `@ajcr`'s comment is better.  There is a difference between 'buffer object' and the address of the arrays data buffer.

============

I haven't used the `data` attribute much.  One of the few cases has been to create an array using the `ndarray` function

[how can I specify the memory address of a Numpy array using ctypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41223030/how-can-i-specify-the-memory-address-of-a-numpy-array-using-ctypes)

```
In [806]: np.ndarray((4,),buffer=A.data, dtype=int, offset=12)
Out[806]: array([3, 4, 5, 6])
In [807]: np.ndarray((4,),buffer=B.data, dtype=int, offset=16)
Out[807]: array([4, 5, 6, 7])
```

================

`A.data` just prints its `repr`, and is just as non-informative as:

```
In [808]: o=object()
In [809]: o
Out[809]: <object at 0xb729fc90>
```