# Reinterpreting NumPy arrays as a different dtype

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, types

Say I have a large NumPy array of `dtype` `int32`

```
import numpy as np
N = 1000  # (large) number of elements
a = np.random.randint(0, 100, N, dtype=np.int32)
```

but now I want the data to be `uint32`. I could do

```py
b = a.astype(np.uint32)
```

or even

```py
b = a.astype(np.uint32, copy=False)
```

but in both cases `b` is a copy of `a`, whereas I want to simply reinterpret the data in `a` as being `uint32`, as to not duplicate the memory. Similarly, using `np.asarray()` does not help.

What *does* work is

```py
a.dtpye = np.uint32
```

which simply changes the `dtype` without altering the data at all. Here's a striking example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-1, 0, 1, 2], dtype=np.int32)
print(a)
a.dtype = np.uint32
print(a)  # shows "overflow", which is what I want
```

My questions are about the solution of simply overwriting the `dtype` of the array:

1. Is this legitimate? Can you point me to where this feature is documented?
2. Does it in fact leave the data of the array untouched, i.e. no duplication of the data?
3. What if I want two arrays `a` and `b` sharing the same data, but view it as different `dtype`s? I've found the following to work, but again I'm concerned if this is really OK to do:

   ```py
   import numpy as np
   a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=np.int32)
   b = a.view(np.uint32)
   print(a)  # [0  1  2  3]
   print(b)  # [0  1  2  3]
   a[0] = -1
   print(a)  # [-1  1  2  3]
   print(b)  # [4294967295  1  2  3]
   ```

   Though this seems to work, I find it weird that the underlying `data` of the two arrays does not seem to be located the same place in memory:

   ```py
   print(a.data)
   print(b.data)
   ```

   Actually, it seems that the above gives different results each time it is run, so I don't understand what's going on there at all.
4. This can be extended to other `dtype`s, the most extreme of which is probably mixing 32 and 64 bit floats:

   ```py
   import numpy as np
   a = np.array([0, 1, 2, np.pi], dtype=np.float32)
   b = a.view(np.float64)
   print(a)  # [0.  1.  2.  3.1415927]
   print(b)  # [0.0078125  50.12387848]
   b[0] = 8
   print(a)  # [0.  2.5  2.  3.1415927]
   print(b)  # [8.  50.12387848]
   ```

   Again, is this condoned, if the obtained behaviour is really what I'm after?

Comment: You can check with `np.shares_memory(a,b)` whether the memory is shared. In all of your example it is shared.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice little function to be aware of!

Comment: I guess you know what you're doing, but be aware that the resulting views in both of your examples have values that are not easy to understand (two's complement signed intergers to unsigned, and two `float32` concatenated to `float64` mixing up significand and exponent bits). Here are more informations about the [`data` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41315712/14277722)

Comment: The `data_buffer` of an array is a 1d C array of bytes.  As long the `dtype` is compatible in size (multiples of 2, 4 or what ever), you can `view` it in different ways.  Just looking at the view doesn't harm anything, though the display might not make sense.  Using it to change values may produce unpredictable results - such as the negative `int32` viewed as `uint32`.

Comment: @hpaulj But it is not unpredictable, you just have to know about the binary formats.

Comment: `a.data` is a memoryview object; its print display is not a memory address (it's the hex version of its `id()`). `a.__array_interface__['data']` is a more useful indicator of where the data_buffer is located.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1. Is this legitimate? Can you point me to where this feature is documented?

This is legitimate. However, using `np.view` (which is equivalent) is better since it is compatible with a static analysers (so it is somehow safer). Indeed, the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/1.22/reference/typing.html?highlight=dtype#ndarray) states:

> It’s possible to mutate the `dtype` of an array at runtime. [...]
> This sort of mutation is not allowed by the types. Users who want to write statically typed code should instead use the `numpy.ndarray.view` method to create a view of the array with a different `dtype`.

> 2. Does it in fact leave the data of the array untouched, i.e. no duplication of the data?

Yes. Since the array is still a **view** on the same internal memory buffer (a basic byte array). Numpy will just reinterpret it differently (this is directly done the C code of each Numpy computing function).

> 3. What if I want two arrays `a` and `b` sharing the same data, but view it as different `dtypes`? [...]

`np.view` can be used in this case as you did in your example. However, the result is *platform dependent*. Indeed, Numpy just [reinterpret bytes of memory](https://numpy.org/doc/1.22/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html#numpy.ndarray.view) and theoretically the representation of negative numbers can change from one machine to another. Hopefully, nowadays, all mainstream modern processors use use the [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations)). This means that a `np.in32` value like `-1` will be reinterpreted as `2**32-1 = 4294967295` with a view of type `np.uint32`. Positive signed values are unchanged. As long as you are aware of this, this is fine and the behaviour is predictable.

> 4. This can be extended to other `dtypes`, the most extreme of which is probably mixing 32 and 64 bit floats.

Well, put it shortly, *this is really like playing fire*. In this case this certainly **unsafe** although it may work on your specific machine. Let us venturing into troubled waters.

First of all, the documentation of `np.view` states:

> The behavior of the view cannot be predicted just from the superficial appearance of `a`. It also depends on exactly how `a` is stored in memory. Therefore if `a` is C-ordered versus fortran-ordered, versus defined as a slice or transpose, etc., the view may give different results.

The thing is Numpy reinterpret the pointer using a C code. Thus, AFAIK, the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) applies. This means that reinterpreting a `np.float32` value to a `np.float64` cause an **undefined behaviour**. One reason is that the alignment requirements are not the same for `np.float32` (typically 4) and `np.float32` (typically 8) and so reading an unaligned `np.float64` value from memory **can cause a crash** on some architecture (eg. POWER) although x86-64 processors support this. Another reason comes from the compiler which can over-optimize the code due to the strict aliasing rule by making wrong assumptions in your case (like a `np.float32` value and a `np.float64` value cannot overlap in memory so the modification of the view should not change the original array). However, since Numpy is called from CPython and no function calls are inlined from the interpreter (probably not with Cython), this last point should not be a problem (it may be the case be if you use Numba or any JIT though). Note that this is safe to get an `np.uint8` view of a `np.float32` since it does not break the strict aliasing rule (and the alignment is Ok). This could be useful to efficiently serialize Numpy arrays. The opposite operation is not safe (especially due to the alignment).

**Update about last section:** a deeper analysis from the Numpy code show that some part of the code like [type-conversion functions](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/f32f47d58e51111a9c995b2f53dab0d0bdb1c927/numpy/core/src/multiarray/lowlevel_strided_loops.c.src#L841) perform a safe type punning using the `memmove` C call, while some other functions like all basic [unary operators](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/f32f47d58e51111a9c995b2f53dab0d0bdb1c927/numpy/core/src/umath/fast_loop_macros.h#L135) or [binary ones](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/f32f47d58e51111a9c995b2f53dab0d0bdb1c927/numpy/core/src/umath/fast_loop_macros.h#L205) do not appear to do a proper type punning yet! Moreover, such feature is *barely tested* by users and tricky corner cases are likely to cause weird *bugs* (especially if you read and write in two views of the same array). Thus, *use it at your own risk*.